# Android - Socket for statusmessages in a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I'm fairly new to Android programming and Java in general. I'm trying to hook up my Android Device with my EV3 LEGO Brick via a Socket connection.

- App needs to connect to the EV3 (Server) (on a button press)
- Connection needs to be held open
- Server sends messages from time to time

I tried to do that yesterday prototypically in an empty activity with an async task - but I'm afraid that the async task is probably not what I'm looking for as it seems to close the connection right away.

```
 public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean hazardLights, trunkOpen, trunkClosed;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);


        /*
        No Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        */
        TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View view) {

                // the communication channel to the server should be opened
                new handleComm().execute();

                Snackbar.make(view, "Communication should be openend", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public class handleComm extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        InputStream inp = null;
        InputStreamReader isr;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

        String result = "";
        @Override protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                //create a socket to make the connection with the server
                Socket socket = new Socket("10.0.1.1", 1111);

                inp = socket.getInputStream();
                isr = new InputStreamReader(inp, "UTF-8");
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);

                // hold the channel open --> while
                while(true)
                {
                   String line = bufferedReader.readLine();

                   if(line.equals("Haza"))
                   {
                            setStatus("Communication received");
                       // do some stuff
                   }
                }


                /*finally {
                    //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                    // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                    socket.close();
                }*/

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);
                result = "oh noes";
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.d("MyAsyncTask", "Received result: " + result);
        }
    }

    public void setStatus(String status)
    {
        TextView statusTXT = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
        statusTXT.setText(status);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Do you have an idea or a code sample on how to create my idea? I guess it needs to be done in a thread, but I'm not sure how to realize and programm that.

Thanks!

Comment: For a bloody beginner, that's a mouthful to chew ... I suggest you investigate into "[Android Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)". I guess you will need one. Concerning the question - I think it is a bit broad for SO.

Comment: Your code should be performing what you want, not sure if Asynctask will complain will an infinite task, sure you will be better using a simple new Thread(), how you know its not working is it throwing any exception? can you post it?

Comment: It's not throwing an exception. But App 1 controls the server and I can see the reactions on the server. However the debugger is not going into the communication handling.

I can see that the server is sending messages if I use the app TCPClient on my Android device.